# Problem when using json.Unmarshal() on a byte array

Tags: arrays, json, go

I have a struct for image data

```
type ImageData struct {
    Name string
    Data []byte
}
```

The Data field is an image converted to bytes.

I have `jsonImages` like `[{"Data":<many-many bytes>, "Name":"abracadabra"}]` and `var imagesData []ImageData`. And when I try to use `json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonImages), &imagesData)` as a result of `fmt.Println(imagesData)` I receive `[{abracadabra []}]`.   The Data field is empty. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is the error returned from json.Unmarshal?  json.Unmarshal assumes that []byte values are encoded in base64. What encoding is used for your image data?

Comment: @MuffinTop thanks for comment. There is no error. Everything goes well, but one of the fields is empty. I get image data from ios app by local http server. And honestly I don't know what specific encoding type it is. There is type called Data, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

I tried replicating the scenario with below snippet
It worked fine.Is this the one you are trying:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Imgdta struct {
    Name string
    Dta  []byte
}

func main() {
    var Imgdta1 Imgdta
    var Imgdta2 Imgdta
    Imgdta1.Dta = []byte("asfafalsffa")
    Imgdta1.Name = "asnakakad"
    imgjson, _ := json.Marshal(Imgdta1)
    fmt.Println("Input Json:-", string(imgjson))
    json.Unmarshal((imgjson), &Imgdta2)
    fmt.Println((Imgdta2))
}
```

...
Result:

```
Input Json:- {"Name":"asnakakad","Dta":"YXNmYWZhbHNmZmE="}
{asnakakad [97 115 102 97 102 97 108 115 102 102 97]}
```

URL - https://play.golang.org/p/LQNwLqDTvt5